# Cannot find symbol with Guice's method createInjector

Tags: java, maven, javafx, guice

I am getting a weird error with my project, I added Guice to my dependencies in the POM.xml, everything seems fine the IDE gives the suggestions an all, even when I was writing the code to start the Injector it suggested me the method I wanted to use, but later it marks it in red, saying it cannot be found, I have never experienced something like this. Maybe I am forgetting something. Can anyone help me?

My project is a maven JavaFX desktop app.

This is the output of the error

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/Users/ochamo/Documents/Proyectos/apde-alumnus/APDEAlumnus "-Dmaven.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf" "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=52291:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2019.1 com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:8.8.3:jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building APDE-Alumnus 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> javafx-maven-plugin:8.8.3:jar (default-cli) > [jfxjar]package @ APDE-Alumnus >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ APDE-Alumnus ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 10 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ APDE-Alumnus ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 13 source files to /Users/ochamo/Documents/Proyectos/apde-alumnus/APDEAlumnus/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/ochamo/Documents/Proyectos/apde-alumnus/APDEAlumnus/src/main/java/edu/apde/alumnus/main/Main.java:[22,47] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class createInjector
  location: class com.google.inject.Guice
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.584 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-03T12:10:32-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the Guice dependency in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
   <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The code I am using to bootstrap my main class in

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

       try {
           final Injector injector = new Guice.createInjector(new MainModule()); // this is the source of the error It cannot find createInjector.

           FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
           fxmlLoader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/fxml/main/main-view.fxml"));
           System.out.printf("location: " + fxmlLoader.getLocation());
           GridPane root = fxmlLoader.load();
           Scene scene = new Scene(root);

           primaryStage.setScene(scene);
           primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
           primaryStage.show();
       } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createInjector` method is a ***static*** method (see the [Javadocs](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Guice.html#createInjector-java.lang.Iterable-))...

```
public static Injector createInjector(Module... modules) {
    return createInjector((Iterable)Arrays.asList(modules));
}
```

When you attempt to invoke it like this ...

```
new Guice().createInjector(...)
```

... you are attempting to invoke an ***instance*** method and this does not compile since there is no instance method named `createInjector` in the `Guice` class..

Instead, you should invoke it like this:

```
Guice.createInjector(...)
```

To be clear; instead of invoking `new Guice()` you just invoke on `Guice`.

For background:

- An ***instance*** method must be invoked on an instance of its class; to invoke a instance method, you must create an instance of the class in which the method is defined. For example: `new Foo().doIt()`
- A ***static*** method is invoked without creating an instance of its class; to invoke a static method you just reference it by its class name. For example: `Foo.doIt()`

Comment: In Java, one can invoke a static method on an instance—though it is highly discouraged. The problem in the OP's code is `new Guice.createInjector(...)` (no parenthesis after `Guice`). The compiler thinks this is referencing a nested _class_ of `Guice` named `createInjector`, which obviously doesn't exist. This is caused by the erroneous `new`, without which the syntax is correct for invoking a static method.

Comment: OMG, I didn't notice that, I am so sorry for bothering you. Thank you both of you.

Comment: Absolutely mate. You helped me with my error. I can't believe I failed to notice something that basic xD.